# How to make an EditText with a Spinner Dropdown

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext, android-spinner

How can I make an EditText with a suggestions drop-down in Android?

For example, if I were to make an app that allows a user to enter a distance and a unit, I might want to have an EditText for the unit with a Spinner drop-down that lists miles, meters, and kilometers. However, my user may want to enter their distance in smoots, and since that is not a pre-provided option they should be able to type it in.

I basically want something like what is shown on [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20170716133618/https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) but where the user could input "school" where the first "Home" is without having to click the "Custom" option.

Comment: Have you tried using `AutoCompleteTextView`?

Comment: @Ayush Khare I have tried AutoCompleteTextView, however, it doesn't seem to give me what I want. When I bring it into focus it gives me random suggestions (My name, email, I assume form related things I've typed before) and then will only give me the suggestions I provided it if I start to type them. I want it to only give me the suggestions I provided it and not care what I've typed in already, similar to how a Spinner's drop-down works.

Comment: You can set a adapter in it to provide you with the suggestions you passed in the adapter

Comment: Would you provide an example in an answer?

Comment: the always use of the multiautocomlpletetextview to get multiple record from  edittext